# Anylogic: increase the distance that camera covers

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Is there any option to increase the distance that camera in 3D space covers? in big geographically models, when we zoom out most of environment is not shown anymore which seems that is because the camera range is limited.

Any solution?

a sample image is below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your 3D window, go to advanced settings, and increase the far clipping property to whatever you need

[image: far clipping]